# Improving images download performance in Java

Tags: java

I have few files with urls to some images that i want to download but with my code it seems to take quite long . It takes 4 and half minute to download 100mb. My IPS lets my download from steam at 20mb/s so i thinks its quite slow.
Here is my code, what could i improve?

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Downloader {
static File file;
Scanner scanner;
static ArrayList<URL> links;

public Downloader(String filesPath)
{
    file = new File(filesPath);
    links = new ArrayList<URL>();

}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Downloader downloader = new Downloader("links");
    downloader.read(file);
    downloader.download(links);
}

public void read(File files) throws FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException
{
    String line;
    for(File file:files.listFiles())
    {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while(scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            if(line.matches(".*jpg")||line.matches(".*png"))
            {
                URL url = new URL(line);
                links.add(url);
            }
        }
    }


}
public void download(ArrayList<URL> links) throws IOException
{
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int i =0;
    ArrayList<URL> tempLinks = new ArrayList<URL>(links);
    for(URL url: tempLinks){
        URLConnection myURLConnection = url.openConnection();
        myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        myURLConnection.connect();
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(myURLConnection.getInputStream());

        String[] parts = url.toString().split("/cards/|\\.");
        System.out.println(parts[2]);


        if(url.toString().matches(".*jpg")){
        File file = new File("downloaded\\"+parts[2]+".jpg");
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", file);
        }else{
            File file = new File("downloaded\\"+parts[2]+".png");
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", file);
        }

        i++;
    }

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(endTime-startTime + " ms");
}
```

}

EDIT:

```
URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
InputStream is = url.openStream();
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

byte[] b = new byte[2048];
int length;

while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
    os.write(b, 0, length);
}

is.close();
os.close();
```

}

Comment: Why do you decode the JPG file you download to an image, and then re-encode the image to JPG again, instead of just saving what you download directly to a file? Anyway, to speed things up, download the images in parallel, not in sequence.

Comment: @JBNizet By parallel thing, you mean async tasks? And in which part of code i do decode and then re-encode? You mean i could just save image i have in BufferedImage?

Comment: No, I mean you don't need ImageIO and BufferedImage at all. All you need is to write the bytes you get from the server to the file. In parallel means that you would have several threads downloading images in parallel. There are many ways to achieve that.

Comment: @JBNizet I added some code to the main post, something like this would be better?

Comment: Yes, much better. But you could also just use `Files.copy(url.openStream(), destinationFile.toPath())`.

Comment: @JBNizet The only problem with this solution is that i can't use it because i'm getting 403 Forbidden error from server, that is why i used User-Agent but i can use it with stream or maybe can i?

Comment: And if you could point me in a direction to do it in a parallel way that would be great.

Comment: What prevents you from setting the user agent with this solution? The point is that you can just use Files.copy to copy the content from the InputStream (whatever the way you get it), to a file. Regarding threads, You can use a parallelStream on your ArrayList, or an Executor obtained from Executors.newFixedThreadPool(), for example.

Comment: @JBNizet The only thing that  Files.copy(myURLConnection.getInputStream(),file.toPath()); did was creating files but didnt download any data, every file is 0B size

Comment: Then your server probably sends back a response containing 0 bytes. It works fine here: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/019510cb759646e8da3260050deeadcd